# Code generation from WSDL: Property "Error" is already defined, but there is no nothing called "Error" in the files

Tags: java, maven, soap, cxf, wsdl2java

We are attempting to generate Java classes from this wsdl file: http://ws.infotorg.no/xml/NE/EDROnline/2017-01-23/EDROnline.wsdl.

To do generate the code we use `maven` as a build tool, where we have specified the following build plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/src</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/EDROnline.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/EDROnline.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

We run `mvn clean package` to execute the build.

**We obtain the following errors**:

1. https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EVRY/InfotorgForetak/2015-12-01/include/ResultatregnskapOgBalanse.xsd [0,0]: Property "Aar" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
2. https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EurotaxGlass/Bruktbilverdi/2016-03-09/Bruktbilverdi.xsd [0,0]: Property "Error" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

We see in the following stackoverflow answer: [XSD "property already defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384525/xsd-property-already-defined) that these errors can be fixed by simply renaming said properties to something else, and the renaming can be specified using a *bindings* file. We inspect the
`.xsd` files to figure out the XPath.

**Solution for error 1:** The first error was simple, in our bindings file fixed the error by specfiying:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EVRY/InfotorgForetak/2015-12-01/include/ResultatregnskapOgBalanse.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Aar']">
            <jaxb:property name="ResultatregnskapOgBalanseAar" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

**Attempted solution for error 2:** In the xsd file of the second error we could not find any properties named "Error". However there were three properties with the name "error". We try to resolve those:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EurotaxGlass/Bruktbilverdi/2016-03-09/Bruktbilverdi.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="BruktbilverdiComplexTypeError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="BruktbilverdiElementError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="BruktbilverdiAttributeError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Thus the whole bindings file is:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EVRY/InfotorgForetak/2015-12-01/include/ResultatregnskapOgBalanse.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Aar']">
            <jaxb:property name="ResultatregnskapOgBalanseAar" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EurotaxGlass/Bruktbilverdi/2016-03-09/Bruktbilverdi.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="BruktbilverdiComplexTypeError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="BruktbilverdiElementError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="BruktbilverdiAttributeError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And we still obtain the same second error. We have obtained *every* `.xsd` file that is imported and search through every one of them, and none of them as anything called "Error".

#### What we want

Solve error 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the error. Using a program called SoapUI I managed to download all the "dependencies" of the WSDL file. In a directory with all said files I use `grep -r error .` to search for all files containing "error". It found two files:

1. Bruktbilverdi.xsd: `targetNamespace=http://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EurotaxGlass/Bruktbilverdi/2012-08-27/Bruktbilverdi.xsd`
2. Bruktbilverdi_1.xsd: `targetNamespace=http://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EurotaxGlass/Bruktbilverdi/2016-03-09/Bruktbilverdi.xsd`

The files has similar content, I am not sure why both are listed as dependencies (there were many nested levels of imports, it is hard to keep track)

Anyways, I added another specification to rename for the other file as well to the bindings file, resulting in:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EVRY/InfotorgForetak/2015-12-01/include/ResultatregnskapOgBalanse.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Aar']">
            <jaxb:property name="ResultatregnskapOgBalanseAar" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EurotaxGlass/Bruktbilverdi/2016-03-09/Bruktbilverdi.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="Bruktbilverdi2016ElementError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://ws.infotorg.no/xml/EurotaxGlass/Bruktbilverdi/2012-08-27/Bruktbilverdi.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='error']">
            <jaxb:property name="Bruktbilverdi2012ElementError" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

which resolved the error. Altough I still find it odd that the error message states "Error" with capital E, but I could only find properties with a smal case "e"